# Is there any reason to use locks files over flock?

Tags: c, unix, file-locking

With lock files I mean: Create a file to lock a resource and delete it when releasing it again.

Comment: Can you show some example codes detailing your thoughts?

Comment: You might get some better quality answers if you provide some more information about the specific context you are working in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly from the man page:

```
NOTES
    flock() does not lock files over NFS.  Use fcntl(2) instead: that does work over NFS, given
    a sufficiently  recent version of Linux and a server which supports locking.
```

I'm not saying using lock files is the better option over NFS, though.

Comment: `fcntl` locks or `lockf` should be used instead. `flock` is deprecated but plenty of broken software insists on still trying to use it...

Answer (score 1):

some reasons not to use flock():

It does not work over NFS.

It is just an advisory lock, even if you use a lock there is no guarantee other processes will respect it.